# IE Conditional Checks

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, if-statement, cross-browser

In javascript, I have a property of an object I'm trying to access only if it is usable, so I do conditional null/undefined checks before using the object.

```
if( object !== undefined && object != null ) // Occurs in IE8
{
    // Use object
    // Object.someProperty
}
```

On FF & Chrome, the defined behavior is as expected.  When they see object is null, it doesn't go inside the if statement.  However, in IE, it complains about how "someProperty" should not be accessed, because Object is null, and goes in anyways.  But that's why my conditional checks are there for, and FF & Chrome realizes it.

**My question is, why is it even in the *if statement* attempting to execute lines using the object when there are conditional checks stopping it?**

Furthermore, **the solution** to this problem is as follows:

```
if( object !== undefined && object != null && true )
{
    // Use object
    // Object.someProperty
}
```

Notice the "&& true" after the undefined and null check.  This seems to force IE to realize the condition should really evaluate to false, and it works as expected.

So although there seems to be a way to "make it work", my above question still stands.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Is this IE8 only? have you tried other IE versions?

Comment: Show what `object` is

Comment: Show a real test case that we can reproduce please. Usually `object != null` is enough as loose comparison with `null` also type coerces to `undefined`.

Comment: `undefined != null // false`, so you don't need to `!==` check against `undefined` if you're `!=` checking against `null`.

Comment: Let me try and reproduce this on jsfiddle

Comment: can you give us the error you're receiving?

Answer (score 2):

`object` should only be undefined if you don't define or declare it, and `object` should only be `null` if you explicitly set it as `null`.

An example of `object` being `undefined`:

```
var object;
```

An example of `object` being `null`:

```
var object = null;
```

The way I'd check for it is with:

```
if (object) {

}
```

which would make sure that `object` isn't falsey. To be falsey, it is one of the following values:

```
false
0
-0
""
null
undefined
NaN
```

If you're not sure that `object` was ever declared, you need to check its type:

```
if (typeof object !== "undefined") {

}
```

But if you need to also see if it's not null, then use:

```
if (typeof object !== "undefined" && object !== null) {

}
```

Of course, you could combine the `typeof` check with it being truthy:

```
if (typeof object !== "undefined" && object) {

}
```

If you need to later check if it has a property, use:

```
if ("someProperty" in object) {

}
```

Comment: `NaN` and `-0` are falsey too.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I literally just realized `NaN` was before you commented. Didn't think about `-0` though. I'll add them both. Thanks :)

Comment: I've tried "typeof obj !== "undefined"" and my first attempt to solve this actually used if( !obj ).  Used practically every type of invalid data check to make sure it wouldn't go in the if statement.  I'm trying to reproduce it on JSFiddle.  Did not know about those non-falsey values though, thanks.

Comment: @Ryan Well, I mistyped...I meant to say I'd use `if (object) {` - note there's no `!`. But yeah, any of those falsey values will evaluate as false in an `if` statement...they're aren't **equal to** false